# MDS config manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, master-data-services

Every time I open the Master Data Services Configuration Manager, all options that I previously configured are blank. The service is working fine but aparently the manager doesnt keep the configs saved.

Is it supposed to behave this way or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the installs I've done this appears to be a bug.  Also I've found the integration with DQS to be quite flakey - particularly via the add-ins in Excel (for example the DQS add-in doesn't always appear or is 'disabled').

I also read a long thread on the MSDN forums about the need to install MDS on a domain-joined machine.  That thread appears to have been removed.  I had this problem on RC0 and RTM bits (i.e. failed install).

Also - here's a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487039%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of possible install errors.  Finally, [here's](http://www.bimonkey.com/2012/04/build-your-own-sql-2012-demo-machine-part-4-installing-sql-server-twice/) a complete install, with a link to another known problem, trying to install MSD on a domain controller (scroll down for the MDS install section)

Comment: thanks lynn! yeah thats annoying.  When I installed I just clicked next to be honest, did not realize the details on your link. I'll leave it for now and hope it doesnt cause any mote issues, it is an evaluation intall anyway.